# Create a dynamically extendable layout and add buttons when extended

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a custom header for my Android app using a RelativeLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/header"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="@drawable/header_bg">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/header_overflow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/header_overflow" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like to have it extend and become populated with buttons on the extended part when the **ImageButton** above is pressed. Exactly like this:

[image]

[image]

Shown: before clicking the button and after (on the original program I am trying to copy). ignore the scribbles since it's not my screenshot

Is this possible in Android? And if so, how would i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to implement this library, follow this [link here](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5798) it is free to use and also available on GitHub

Comment: Thanks! i even searched  'Android expandable layout' and didnt find anything

Comment: If you find this helpful, feel free to up vote it and select it as a correct answer